# In PHP, how do you guess the URL to a certain file, given her disk path?

Tags: php, file, path, directory

This sounds confusing but isn't. Here is the problem:

1. application is hosted at www.site.com/app
2. in /app, there's a htaccess rerouting any non-existing files or directories to index.php
3. index.php does `$method = end(explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));` and calls it method
4. now, method could be CSS, so CSS routine needs to take the css file and replace any `url(images/` with `url(http://site.com/app/images`

The problem is "guessing" http://site.com/app/images, because REQUEST_URI can range anywhere from the cleanest **site.com/images** and up to the dirtiest **http://ex.gau.mit.edu/~jonas/site/projects/2012/app/ignoredmethod/more/ignored/methods/css**

Without specifying the script URL, how can I guess the images folder URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SCRIPT_NAME` will be really useful here.

```
define('URL', (dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) == "/" ? "" : (dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])));
```

Usage:

```
echo "<a href='http://$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]/".URL."/images/image.jpg'>image</a>";
```